# How do I check if my string starts with a certain word in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do some sort of license system.

But there is diffrent kinds of licenses.
There is a Personal, Team, and Admin license. The license looks like

```
<License type>-<Randomly generated 50 characters string>
```

EX:

```
Personal-imiY2cdnpL01EzbZWr2YWzukkJmC3K6BMQpZU2wgfsOehCruDr
```

But when it comes to the license checking, then I want to know what kind of license it is.
So I just want to make a check like `(if $lincense startsWith("Personal")` etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, before asking a question on SO, please always Google first. Googling `How do I check if my string starts with a certain word in PHP?` gives plenty of good resources. Thanks!

Comment: While not directly needed to respond to the question as asked, be sure to add a checkdigit or store the "type" away from the key in question in order to prevent a malicious user from "upgrading" his account type.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) you could also use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$str = 'Personal-imiY2cdnpL01EzbZWr2YWzukkJmC3K6BMQpZU2wgfsOehCruDr';
if (strpos($str, 'Personal') === 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It does not matter much for this example, but keep in mind that strpos will search the whole string while substr only needs to read the first 8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (substr('Personal-imiY2cdnpL01EzbZWr2YWzukkJmC3K6BMQpZU2wgfsOehCruDr', 0, 8) == 'Personal')
```